Change WooCommerce product single add to cart button text only if the product is in cart
In WooCommerce, I would like to update the 'add to cart' text when the corresponding product is removed from the cart.
I have the following code which changes the text when the product is added to the cart:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'already_in_cart_single_product' );
function already_in_cart_single_product( $label ) {
   foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
      $product = $values['data'];
      if( get_the_ID() == $product->get_id() ) {
         $label = __('Product already in Cart. Add again?', 'woocommerce');
      }
   } 
   return $label;
}


And would like something that then reverts the text back again after the product is removed from the cart.

There are some mistakes in your code, try the following instead:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'already_in_cart_single_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
function already_in_cart_single_add_to_cart_text( $add_to_cart_text, $product ) {
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if( $item['data']->get_id() === $product->get_id() ) {
            return __('Product already in Cart. Add again?', 'woocommerce');
        }
    } 
    return $add_to_cart_text;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.
